# How to resize the svg in Angular?

Tags: svg

Here's the svg:

```
<svg width="40%" viewbox="0 0 30 42">
  <path fill="transparent" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5"
        d="M15 3
           Q16.5 6.8 25 18
           A12.8 12.8 0 1 1 5 18
           Q13.5 6.8 15 3z" />
</svg>
```

How to make this svg bigger? Here's the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnqwef?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the **viewBox** (be careful, it's not viewbox) in order to scale changing with and height as you do.

Like in here:

```
<svg width="220" height="220" viewBox="0 0 50 100">
  <path id="scale" fill="transparent" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5"
        d="M15 3
           Q16.5 6.8 25 18
           A-22.8 -22.8 0 1 1 5 18
           Q13.5 6.8 15 3z" />
</svg>

<svg width="440" height="440" viewBox="0 0 50 100">
  <path id="scale2" 
        d="M15 3
          Q20.5 11.8 35 25
          A-28.8 -28.8 0 1 1 0 20
          Q13.5 6.8 15 3z" />
</svg>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4nylpq?file=src/app/app.component.html

and

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxc7nx?file=src/app/app.component.html

SVG with a viewBox will scale to fit the height and width you give it.

[More info](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/svg-viewport-and-viewbox-for-beginners--cms-30844)